# !permit command for Twitch, mIRC/mSL

Tags: hyperlink, mirc, twitch

I want to make a !permit command that will let the user post a link for 20 seconds and not get blocked. If they don't ask a mod to permit them, they will get timed out.

Also I was looking for add a !alwayspermit so they will always have permission to post a link.

I suck at this stuff, real bad.

here's what i have..

```
   on *:TEXT:!permit *:#: {
  if (($nick isop #chan)) 
  { msg # I have permitted the user $+ $2 to post a link for 20 seconds }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, your bot needs to be opped on channel

if someone that is not on permit or alwayspermit list post a link they will get kicked

seconds, press alt+r click "file" then "new" in there paste this code

```
on $@*:text:*:#:{
if ($regex($1-,/(http\72\/\/|www\.).+\.(com|co|uk)/iS)) && ($nick !isop $chan) {
if (!$istok(%permit,$nick,32)) {
  kick $nick $chan You dont have permission to post links in here 
}
}
noop $regex($1-,/^!(del|alwayspermit|permit)\s(\S+)/iS) { 
if ($regml(1) == alwayspermit) && ($nick isop $chan) {
  if ($istok(%permit,$regml(2),32)) {
    msg $chan $regml(2) is already on always permit list
  }
  else {
    set %permit $addtok(%permit,$regml(2),32)
    msg $chan $regml(2) You are now always permited to post links
  }
 }
 if ($regml(1) == permit) && ($nick isop $chan) {
  set %permit $addtok(%permit,$regml(2),32)
  .timerunset 1 20 set %permit $remtok(%permit,$regml(2),1,32)
  msg $chan $regml(2) You have 20 seconds to post a link in here
 }
 if ($regml(1) == del) && ($nick isop $chan) {
  if ($istok(%permit,$regml(2),32)) {
    set %permit $remtok(%permit,$regml(2),1,32)
    msg $chan $regml(2) erased suceffully from always permit list
  }
  else {
    msg $chan $regml(2) is not on always permit list
  }
 }
 }
 }
```

commands:

!permit nick
will add a permitted nick for 20 seconds

!alwayspermit nick
will add a permitted nick permanent

!del nick
will delete a nick from permitted list

Comment: Doesn't work for me, does not timeout anybody when someone puts a link. :(

Comment: have you read the entire post? have you put it into a new file, since on text files cant be without any other text events? "links" are in this way to be allowed http : // www.example.com if you want, we can put http:// or just www., only OPs have permission to add nicks to the list, and the bot (whoever uses the script) must be an OP on room